# Pandas to Pyspark environment

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```py
newlist = []
for column in new_columns:
    count12 = new_df.loc[new_df[col].diff() == 1]
    new_df2=new_df2.groupby(['my_id','friend_id','family_id','colleage_id']).apply(len)
```

There is no option is available in pyspark for getting all length of column

How can we achieve this code into pyspark.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `.diff()` just subtracts the current value of the column with the same column's previous value. you can do that using `lag` window function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally, `apply(len)` is just an aggregation function that would count grouped elements from `groupby`. You can do the very same thing in basic PySpark syntax

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

(df
    .groupBy('my_id','friend_id','family_id','colleage_id')
    .agg(F.count('*'))
    .show()
)
```